# X11 Window Manager SSH TinyCoreLinux

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm booting Tiny Core Linux 6 from a live cd/iso.
Following these guides: http://goo.gl/p1OaP6 , http://goo.gl/n5jd2B ,  http://goo.gl/FYtD67 , http://goo.gl/LsjHu3 , http://goo.gl/wxd1Bp
I've gathered the following.  Run

```
tce-load –wi openssh.tcz
tce-load -wi Xorg-7.7-bin.tcz
```

inside .Xsession replace `-nolisten tcp` with `-ac`

edit /usr/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config to include

```
X11Forwarding Yes
X11UseForwarding Yes
```

change  `/etc/sysconfig/Xserver` to `Xorg`

but I'm still unable to run the following on the remote machine.

```
ssh -X user@ip
apps
Can't open display:
```

Comment: This question is off-topic here. It is better suited for http://superuser.com.

Comment: @n.m. There are similar questions on this site although you are right it is technically better for superuser.com

Comment: When I see one of those I vote to move it over to superuser, but yours cannot be moved because of the bounty.

Comment: It a sysadmin issue around `ssh` so is off-topic here.

Comment: @user1261959 Yes I have checked it, and it doesn't appear to work at all.

Answer (score 2):

First check Display value using :

`echo $DISPLAY`

If it's showing blank then set $DISPLAY variable as below:
If you're still having problems though, you can try setting $DISPLAY to your local box's IP:

```
$ export DISPLAY='<ip_address>:11.0'
```

OR

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

It may work to set it as

```
$ export DISPLAY='127.0.0.1:11.0'
```

Then install xclock and check in ssh with -X and execute 'xclock' command for check.
For me, sometimes

```
ssh -Y
```

Work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but have you actually tried it?  I think it might be a bug and therefore unfixable using typical techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The `-v` option will show debug messages:

```
ssh -v -X xx@ip
```

Try adding `XAuthLocation /usr/local/bin/xauth` or `XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth` to `sshd_config`. The exact location will depend on your system.